# Forming a record of a table from separated values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

*sorry, I couldn't find a better title for the question

ـــــــــــــــــــ

I'm implementing an audit feature, currently using the Audit tables provided by [EntityFramework-Plus](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Audit-%7C-Entity-Framework-Audit-Trail-Context-and-Track-Changes#features),
There are two tables, one that tracks the modification type, and in which entity (every record represents an update by the user):

```
 [AuditEntryID]
,[EntitySetName]
,[EntityTypeName]
,[State]
,[StateName]
,[CreatedBy]
,[CreatedDate]
```

, and in the other table the corresponding changes for each modification, the most important columns are the `OldValue` and the `NewValue` for a specific `PropertyName`:

```
 [AuditEntryPropertyID]
,[AuditEntryID]
,[RelationName]
,[PropertyName]
,[OldValue]
,[NewValue]
```

So to select all edits done on a specific table and for a specific `Id`, I run this query:

```
   SELECT * FROM dbo.[AuditEntryProperties] 
   WHERE AuditEntryID IN (
        SELECT AuditEntryID 
        FROM dbo.[AuditEntryProperties]
        WHERE NewValue = '8b5f8272-8663-451d-8bf8-45d7d5db1529' AND PropertyName = 'CountryId') 
     AND AuditEntryID IN (
        SELECT AuditEntryID 
        FROM dbo.[AuditEntries] 
        WHERE EntitySetName = 'TbCountries' )
```

Since the PK is inserted each time whether it's edit or delete, in the above query I select all the history of the given `Id`.

What I need is that I want to implement feature that the user can go back to a specific record at specific time.
I drew this in paint, it depict the idea:

[image]

the first row is insert state , the second row there are edit on `col1` and `col2` , the third row is and edit on `col1` and `col3`..etc.
the `col1` is a primary key so its inserted every time (it's value doesn't change!)

Now the most recent record is the mod6, and I need to go back to the mod3, so I'll take the `col1` value from mod3 and the `col2` value from mod2, `col3` from mod3, `col4` from mod1.

my problem is how to form a full record of type `TbCountries` from the table `[AuditEntryProperties]` at a specific `AuditEntryID`?

Comment: Without going through the whole project you linked the challenge is your facing is because of the way the audit data is created. It all sounds great to only record the individual values that changed until you run into this situation. And this becomes a total nightmare to reassemble what the entire row looked like at a given point in time. Perhaps if you could share the table structure we can help. But I know I don't want to spend a bunch of time creating data through a project on github to create your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of properties and values using `row_number()`:

```
select aep.*
from (select ae.EntitySetName, aep.propertyname, aep.newvalue,
             row_number() over (partition by ae.EntitySetName, aep.propertyname
                                order by ae.createddate desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from dbo.AuditEntries ae join
           dbo.AuditEntryProperties aep 
           on ae.AuditEntryID = aep.AuditEntryID 
      where ae.createddate < @date and ae.EntitySetName = @tbl
     ) aep
where seqnum = 1;
```

This gives the values as one-per-row.  You can then pivot or use conditional aggregation if you want them on a single row.

Comment: it seems working , actually I couldn't think this problem can be solved..
the only problem here is that the table is vertical, is it possible to form only one record with the column names = the propertyName , also how to add the CountryId to get a specific modification for a specific Id?

Comment: @MohamedAhmed . . . Your question is "What I need is that I want to implement feature that the user can go back to a specific record at specific time. ".  If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question.  This appears to answer the question that you did ask.

Comment: Sorry to not be specific. 
but it turned out that the query get the last modification of the table, not a record in that table, so the `Id` of a record must be used , also it's not clear how the `ae.createddate < @date` works, it's better to use `AuditEntryID` to specify a specific record history. and is it possible to rotate the resulting table (i.e. make it looks like a single record from `TbCountries`)?
And thanks, still think it's great answer.